# jsPDF - .addHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, typeerror, jspdf

I am trying to transform my HMTL page (a form) into a pdf using the jsPDF library, here is what I have done:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    });
});
```

The "btn" is a button that I click to obtain the pdf. The problem I have is that when I click this button, I get the **TypeError: pdf.addHTML() is not a function at HMTLButtonElement.** message. After looking through several posts with the same topics, I don't see what I am missing:

- I have downloaded the jsPDF library
- I have downloaded rasterizehtml in my npm folder (I've also tried to use html2canvas, for the same result)
- I use jspdf.debug.js through the link I could find everywhere
- I have the addhtml.js file in my jsPDF library

Here are my scripts if it can make it clearer:

```
<script src="C:/Users/trist/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/rasterizehtml/dist/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="js/jsPDF-1.3.2/jspdf.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: please check your console for errors, the browser should not be able to load the first script

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3Lyv5pLp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because you are calling two different versions of jsPDF. Try

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.0/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rasterizehtml/1.3.0/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you I don't have the error anymore, now it's working on a simple HTML code but it does not appear to do so on a complex form with different div (it does nothing, no dowload and no error, just rebooting the page), but I'll try to find a solution for that somewhere, thanks again! :)

Comment: @Tristan Please mark this answer as correct (checkmark). As for your new question, post a separate stackoverflow question. If you post it with an example (ie jsfiddle), its more likely to be answered.